# object property undefined after using object.defineProperty or reflet.defineProperty

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have an object, after using defineProperty method, the property I defined is missed. why?

```
    let obj = {
        name:'john',
        age:28
    }
    
    Reflect.defineProperty(obj,'name',{
        get(){
            return this._name
        },
        set(value){
            this._name = value
            return true
        }
    })
    
    console.log(obj)  // output: {age:28}
    console.log(obj.name)  // output: undefined
```

Comment: Well your getter returns the value of `obj._name`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Do not use `Reflect` for this, it's meant to be used in proxy trap handlers. Use `Object.definedProperty`.

Comment: Hi Bergi, I got undefined whatever I use object.defineProperty or reflect.defineProperty. Using obj.name will cause stack overflow, so obj._name is mandatory. Do you have any ways to print the original obj after Object.defineProperty ?   thanks, so much~

Comment: What do you mean by "original object"? You did overwrite the `obj.name` property that had `'john'` as its data value. Your object has no `._name` property. And no, using `obj._name` is not mandatory, you can just as well put `return 'John'` in the getter code or really anything else.

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks so much, I finally understand it. undefined is the default value that set() method returned. Thansk for your help !!~~~~